# The number of books in economics that we need to buy (is/are) three

Tags: subject-verb-agreement

> 1) The number of books in economics that we need to buy (is/are) three.

or

> 2) A number of books in economics that we can buy for the course (is/are) available in the college book store.

Possible answers: 
a)is 
b)are

My approach:

I am confused here why **is** and are **are** used in the 1 and 2 sentence.

What they exactly mean according to subject verb agreement rules.

Answer (score 5):

I believe your confusion is about what is the subject.

> **The number** of books in economics that we need to buy (is/are) three

In this sentence,of books in economics that we need to buy is merely a modifier, the real subject is the number, which is always singular.

> **A number of books** in economics that we can buy for the course (is/are) available in the college book store.

In this case, "a number of" is modifier, not unlike "a lot of", "some". 
So "books" are plural.
So basically, "a number of " is an indiomatic phrase, should be treated as one organic compound word (adj) while "the number of " is basically three ordinary words.  Admittedly I don't think people use the number of ...very often. It is just a grammar point teachers like to use.
(I believe it is "a number of" instead of "the number of". Otherwise it won't make much sense)

Comment: Can you teach me how to identify these kind of tricky sentences? Is there a trick behind this that makes you know?

Comment: Hi, I am not sure if there is any trick. It's just something to memorise, I guess.

Comment: So, what's the difference between "the number of" and "a number of" when determining whether it's a plural or singular?  And, I'd like to see clearer explanation how "a number of" is a modifier and "the number of" is not.

Comment: @VictorBazarov "A number of" is a set phrase meaning "Several". http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/number #2.1. If you remove all the subordinate clauses, the sentences are "The number [singular] *is* three", and "Several books [plural] *are* available".

Answer (score 1):

Even a native speaker of U.S. English (and I suspect some other varieties,
though I can't speak for those) might have some difficulty with these
two sentences.

In English class for native speakers, I recall it being said that if the
subject of a sentence is a phrase such as "a/the number of books",
then the noun *number* is the actual subject, that is, the subject is
singular and the verb would be *is* rather than *are*.

But I think it would be very unusual for a native speaker to say,
"A number of books *is* available in the store."
One would more likely say, "A number of books *are* available in the store."
In other words, "a number of books" is treated idiomatically as if it were
the phrase "some books".

The first sentence speaks of a very specific number of books;
namely, it says that the number is three.
In that case, a native speaker would be likely to view the singular word
"number" as the subject of the sentence, and to say "is" in the 
first example. 
But to be honest, I suspect that many native speakers would still say "are".

So if I were writing these sentences in real life, as an educated native
speaker of U.S. English I would probably write:

> 1) The number of books in economics that we need to buy is three.
>
> 2) A number of books in economics that we can buy for the course are available in the college book store.